# Is there a Charred version for The Blossoms Are Falling?

Tags: online-resources, burning-wheel

I have been wanting to run a game using The Blossoms Are Falling. The site known as Charred has made burning characters extremely easy for me and as such I was looking for a version one could use in The Blossoms Are Falling.